# Thymeleaf dateformat: getting question marks instead of month

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have an object with the property 'date' of java.sql.timestamp. I set this object as parameter in model, and tried to display date in custom format:

```
th:text="${#dates.format(historyItem.date,'MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm')}"
```

But I on view I got this:

> ????. 24, 2017 16:20

How can I deal with it?

Comment: Do you mean `MM` instead of `MMM`?

Comment: No, MM means that month will be displayed as number from 1 to 12, but I want to display month as first three letters, like Jan, Feb, Nov etc. The documentation says that  right format for this is 'MMM'.

Comment: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#dates

Comment: ah okay, which version do you use. The current is 3.0.9.

Comment: What is the vvalue of `historyItem.date`? What is the locale of the browser?

Comment: historyItem.date value is long number. The locale is ru-RU